# Best way to have article text with links on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, hyperlink

I am making an iPhone app that has a bunch of "articles" with certain words that I want to link to other "articles". I need to display the articles in UITableViewCells.

If there is a way to do this without a web view, that's great.

If I need to use a web view, should I just make `<a href>` style links? How can I have it jump to the article without creating a bunch of actual html pages, just have it let my program know that they clicked on that link and then the program goes and finds the appropriate article from a plist or something?

Comment: I was able to complete this exact task using a UIWebView. (Search the iTunes App store for 'Eco Guide'.

You can essentially create an Intranet with all of your html documents located in a directory and have them link with one another.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a test demo using `UIWebView` and it works fine. 
Create two HTML files:home.html and first.html.

```
// home.html
Home page. <a href="first.html">first</a>
// first.html
First page. <a href="home.html">home</a>

//viewDidLoad

self.webView.delegate = self;
NSString *htmlFilePathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home"  ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *htmlFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:htmlFilePathString];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:htmlFileURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];

// webView's delegate:
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}
```